# Возвращение  JSON в PHP

Tags: json, php, codeigniter

У меня есть две функции, одна возвращает все страницы категории, другая все подкатегории. Но почему-то если категорий нет, то функция возвращает [], а если страниц нет, то функция возвращает null, из-за чего это может быть, и как сделать чтобы возврат был [] и там и там?

```
public function category($parent_id=0)
{
    $result = array();
    $this->db->select('id,name');
    $this->db->where('parent_id',$parent_id);
    $this->db->order_by('name','asc');
    $query = $this->db->from('category')->get()->result_array();

    foreach($query as $res) 
    {
        $result[] = array('id'=>$res['id'],'name'=>$res['name'],'count'=>$this->gcpc($res['id']));
    }

    return $this->json($result);
}

public function pages($category=0)
{
    $result = array();
    //Получаем опубликованные страницы
    $this->db->select('id,title,showed');
    $this->db->where('category',$category);
    $this->db->where('post_status','publish');
    $query = $this->db->from('content')->get()->result_array();

    //Устанавливаем доп.поля
    foreach($query as $page){
        $qpage[] = $this->load->module('cfcm')->connect_fields($page,'page');
    }

    //Указываем ненужные данные
    $filter = array('field_place','field_site','field_address','field_email');

    //Отчищаем результат
    $result = $this->clear_result($qpage,$filter);

    //Выводим результат
    return $this->json($result);
}

private function clear_result($arr,$filter) 
{
    foreach($arr as $a) 
    {
        if(is_array($filter))
        {
            foreach($filter as $f)
            {
                unset($a[$f]);
            }
        } else {
            unset($a[$filter]);
        }

        $result[] = $a;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых надо объявить

```
`$qpage = array();`
```

Во вторых проверить число записей в результате выборки. Если 0 сразу $result=array(); и return.
В третьих в функции clear_result сделать проверку на $arr.

```
if (is_array($arr) && count($arr)>0 ){
....
} else {
return array();
}
```